# R GUI with tcltk package: tkget() throws error when reading text property: "[tcl] bad option "get": must be cget or configure"

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

When I run a pure Tcl/Tk script I can read the text property of a label with the cget command:

```
$ wish
% label .lb -text "Read this"
pack .lb
.lb cget -text
.lb
% % Read this
```

If I try to do this in R using the tkget function I get an error:

```
library(tcltk)

tt <- tktoplevel()
lb <- tklabel(tt, text = "Read this")
tkpack(lb)
tkget(lb, "text") # TODO Does not work

> Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] bad option "get": must be cget or configure.
```

**How do I call *tkget* correctly** (there is no proper documentation available)?
Or how could I read the current value of the *text* property another way?

Comment: OK, I have mixed up tkget and tkcget, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
library(tcltk)

tt <- tktoplevel()
lb <- tklabel(tt, text = "Read this", padx=10)
tkpack(lb)
tclvalue(tkcget(lb, "-text"))
tclvalue(tkcget(lb, "-padx"))
tkdestroy(tt)
```

**Lessons learned:**

1. Don't mix up *tkget* with ***tkcget*** (the former is the *get* command of a *text* widget, the latter is a generic command to read widget properties.
2. The widget property that you want to read must be specified as string with a **hyphen** (this is different from the way you specify the same property during creation of the widget in R using tcltk - see the *padx* example in the code above).
3. As usual: You have to convert the result of tkcget from a TCL value into an R value using the **tclvalue** function.

Comment: `cget` stands for “configuration get”, and the underlying property names really do start with a hyphen; it's just the widget constructors on the R side which hide this.